# Eliminar elementos duplicados en una lista de maps Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Cordial saludo compañeros, tengo la siguiente lista de maps

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> subjects = [

  {'subjectName': 'Ingles', 'teacherName': 'Profesor 1'},

  {'subjectName': 'Matematicas', 'teacherName': 'Profesor 2'}

  {'subjectName': 'Ingles', 'teacherName': 'Profesor 1'},
];
```

Como puedo eliminar los map que esten duplicados, donde subjectName se repita?

Intente usar toSet().toList() pero esto solo funciona correctamente cuando no es una lista de maps, lo he utilizado por ejemplo en una lista de strings o de enteros.

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tendrías que crear tu propio filtro, ya que no tienes un map directamente sino un `List`, no es complicado, aquí te dejo la lógica que implementé.

```dart
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> subjects = [
    {'subjectName': 'Ingles', 'teacherName': 'Profesor 1'},
    {'subjectName': 'Matematicas', 'teacherName': 'Profesor 2'},
    {'subjectName': 'Ingles', 'teacherName': 'Profesor 1'},
  ];

  final Map<String, dynamic> mapFilter = {};

  for (Map<String, dynamic> myMap in subjects) {
    mapFilter[myMap['subjectName']] = myMap;
  }

  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> listFilter =
      mapFilter.keys.map((key) => mapFilter[key] as Map<String,dynamic>).toList();

  print(listFilter);
```

Comment: Funciono correctamente lo modifique, para pasar por parámetro la propiedad por la que se debe filtrar muchas gracias diego.